# Why is the #wrapper not the full height of content within it?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I can't seem to find what is missing in this page to make the wrapper wrap the content properly, it only 332px tall for some reason when it should be the height of the content.. It's causing the footer to pull up to the top of the page... Am I missing a closing div or something, I need fresh eyes...

http://tsdexter.com/tests/georgianhome/index.php

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Please post the offending HTML and CSS.  If that link goes dead then this question/answer will be useless.  I am also having a hard time determining which wrapper you are referring to.

Comment: I'm not sure which part is the offending HTML/CSS. I could post it all but it's over 1000 lines.... I'm referring to the <div id="wrapper">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using some divs with float and some without, which can cause the issues you are seeing.

Try placing this:

```
<p style="clear: both; height: 1px;"><!-- --></p>
```

just before the wrapper div closes.

Comment: You sir are correct! Why the person who built the original used so many floats instead of positioning is beyond me! Added a <div class="clear"></div> at the end of the wrapper and we're good. I'd prefer to get rid of all the non semantic markup but I can't be bother to go and fix everything they've floated, unnecessarily.

Comment: I've read somewhere that there are two kinds of CSS'ers in the world. The floaters, and the clearers. Glad I could be of some use.

Comment: This can also be done with a div, which is what I have used in the past.

Comment: I'm the 3rd kind - only float things that should be floated like an image in a paragraph of text - using positioning for everything else. That way I don't need to clear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What's more concerning is how your footer is acting. And, I also cannot determine which wrapper you are referring to.

Comment: Do you mean how the first DIV in the footer is at the top and the second DIV is at the bottom? I'm not sure what's causing that either... Also not sure what's confusing about which wrapper I'm referring too.. I'm referring to <div id="wrapper">

Comment: Ah, I figured out the footer, it's because of the clear both on the content-footer. But I still need the footer below the wrapper and the wrapper to be full height.